# Why do people use div.border in a css file insead of just .border?

Tags: css

I was wondering why some css files use div.border instead of .border to list a sector in CSS. I have seen it used for multiple sectors like `div.footer {color:#000000;}` instead of just `.footer {color:#000000;}`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Don't forget that `div.footer` has "more binding power" than `.footer` so it can also be used to overwrite a more general `.footer` style from elsewhere...

Comment: @pst, or rather [a higher specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity)

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 reasons you might want to specify the element:

1. You are applying the class to multiple types of elements and need
   to add to or override the rules for particular elements.
2. You wish to provide contextual information in the style sheet
   (usually for other developers)
3. You need extra specificity to override a style rule from another class.

In general I think #1 is a bad idea except for some utility classes (like floats or clears) and I think that sort of thing is better handled by using a preprocessor like Saas with mixins

The second case I think is of dubious value. If you run into the third case (much like sprinkling in `!important`), you may want to refactor things to avoid having to do this. In any event be aware that if they aren't needed adding elements to the selector just slows matching down

Comment: I don't think that #1 is generally bad (+1 for mentioning it, in fact :-)

Answer (score 1):

The presence of the "div" before the dot means that the selector only applies to DOM elements of the type div.

So, for instance, if you have a class called "foo",

```
.foo {
    color:#ff0000;
}
```

It would make the text inside of  red.  Using div.foo would cause the directives only to apply to divs of that class.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the difference between `<div class="border">Div with border</div>` and `<p class="border">Paragraph with border</p>`. The style of `.border { ... }` would affect both of these, while `div.border{ ... }` would only affect the div.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the .border class rules you are writing  to apply only to div containers, as opposed to table containers or other elements, that's how you do it. There are many good articles on CSS selectors, of which [this](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_class.htm) is but one.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, prepending the div element to the footer class will ensure that the styles are only applied to divs with class 'footer', and not other elements with class 'footer'.

Ideally you would just use .footer if you know for sure you will only use the class on one particular DOM element.  Prepending the class with a DOM element is not necessary and has a negative effect on rendering performance (OK, it doesn't have much effect in reality, but it's still inefficient).